# Message field is deleted when 2 people write at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to chat, it's almost over, but if someone presses the enter key while 2 people are typing at the same time, the message writing place is cleaned. How can I get rid of this? I figured out why this happened, but I couldn't figure out how to make it one-sided.

Node.JS;

```
const express = require('express')
const socket = require('socket.io')

const app = express()
const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    console.log("server");
})

app.use(express.static('public'))

const io = socket(server)

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(socket.id)

    socket.on('chat', data => {
        io.sockets.emit('chat', data)
    })

    socket.on('typing', data => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('typing', data)
    })
})
```

JavaScript;

```
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

const sender = document.getElementById('sender');
const message = document.getElementById('message');
const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submitBtn');
const output = document.getElementById('output');
const feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (sender.value != '' && message.value != '') {
        socket.emit('chat', {
            message: message.value,
            sender: sender.value,
        });
        sender.disabled = true;
    }
})

socket.on('chat', data => {
    feedback.innerHTML = ''
    output.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + data.sender + '     : </strong>' + data.message + '</p>'
    message.value = '';
})

message.addEventListener('keypress', () => {
    socket.emit('typing', sender.value)
})

socket.on('typing', data => {
    socket.on('typing', data => {
        feedback.innerHTML = '<p>' + data + ' typing...    </p>';
        // clear feedback after one second of     inactivity
        setTimeout(() => {
            feedback.innerHTML = ''
        }, 5000);
    })
})
```

Comment: your `socket.on('chat')` executes `message.value = ''`. Delete that line and add it to the bottom of the callback function of  `submitBtn.addEventListener('click')`. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Hi, I was looking at something when I was bored and I saw your message. Maybe it won't make sense, but I thought I'd write that it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code:

```
socket.on('chat', data => {
    feedback.innerHTML = ''
    output.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + data.sender + '     : </strong>' + data.message + '</p>'
    message.value = '';
})
```

We can see that you set `message.value` to `''` when a `chat` action occurs. Prevent this by deleting `message.value = '';`.

After, your code should look like the following:

```
socket.on('chat', data => {
    feedback.innerHTML = ''
    output.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + data.sender + '     : </strong>' + data.message + '</p>'
})
```